# Android Screen Densities: how many densities?

Tags: android, layout, screen

I am developing an Android app that downloads images from an S3 bucket and displays them full screen on the phone.

How many different densities should I create in the S3 bucket for each image, in order to include both phones and tablets?

What about for Apple devices (again, both phones and tablets)?

*Note*: I have read the Android [Supporting Multiple Densities](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) help page. I have also found similar questions on Stackoverflow, but they are 3-4 year old and new devices have popped up since then.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could include one of them or all of them, that depends on how many densities you want your images to look good. The answer to this question depends on how much you care about it. If you don't care and just want it to work, add only one.

For Android you have:

```
ldpi (low) ~120dpi
mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
hdpi (high) ~240dpi
xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi
```

And for iPhone:

```
normal
 @2x
 @3x
```

Comment: Thanks and apologies if the question offended anyone.